# Teleporation and shrinkage

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, teleportation

In what short story did teleportation have the side effect of making you smaller each time? I am interested in the potential side effects of this mode of travel.

Comment: Do you remember any other details to this story? You can find a list of helpful diagnostic questions at http://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info to ferret out more details.

Comment: Mike Teavee in Charlie and the Chocolate Factory?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RcyyDYucIXk I agree this sounds exactly like Mike Teavee in this scene. Wouldn't call CatCF a "short story" though.

Comment: Doesn't the Teraport from Schlock Mercenary do something like that?

Comment: Yeah, IIRC the Teraport uses some small fraction of the mass of whatever is being teraported in order to power it.